# ArcPy Feature Class to Feature Class blank results - ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, feature-class

I have this Feature Class to Feature Class script that creates a feature class of patient visits for each store for every month for every year it has been open. However, when I run the script it will create feature classes by month and year with the correct labels, for example (Jan2015_NWPatientVisits2000Gresham), but when I look at the attribute table it contains no data.

I'm sure I am missing something small, but I just can't seem to figure out what it is.

Here is my script:

```
import arcpy

# Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\arcGIS_Shared\Python\CenterHeatMaps.gdb"

#Declare variables
fc = 'Open_Store_Centers'
fields = ['USER_market_id','USER_Store_ID','USER_Store_Center_Name']
fieldname = 'USER_market_id'

#Define WHERE clause statement
whereclause = """{} = 2000""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, fieldname))
sqlclause = (None, 'Order By USER_market_id, USER_Store_ID')

# loop through months
years = [2015, 2016, 2017]
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

for year in years:
    for month in months:
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_table = fc, field_names = fields, where_clause=whereclause, sql_clause=(None, 'ORDER BY USER_market_id, USER_Store_ID')) as cursor:
        #Loop through each row established in cursor
            for row in (cursor):
            # Set local variables for FeatureClasstoFeatureClass
                inFeatures = "PatientVisitsGeocoded"
                outLocation = r"C:\arcGIS_Shared\Python\CenterHeatMaps.gdb"
                outFeatureClass = "{2}{3}_NWPatientVisits{0}{1}".format(row[0], row[2], month, year)
                delimitedfield = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(arcpy.env.workspace,"USER_CenterID")
                expression = delimitedfield + "= {0}".format(row[1]) + " AND USER_DOSYear = {0}".format(year) + " AND USER_DOSMonth = '{0}'".format(month) 

#         Execute FeatureClassToFeatureClass
                arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(inFeatures, outLocation, outFeatureClass, expression)

        #Print Results
                print(row[2])
                count = arcpy.GetMessageCount()
                print (arcpy.GetMessage(count-1))
```

Comment: Why don't you just use [Select](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/select.htm) instead of Feature Class to Feature Class?

Comment: @GISGe I was unaware that `Select` existed. However, I think I'm close to getting this to work. I realized that CenterID and StoreID were really the same thing but had different data types so I changed them both into "Text". Now I'm getting an error saying the following is an invalid SQL statement `expression = """{0} = {1} AND USER_DOSMonth = '{2}' AND USER_DOSYear = {3}""".format(delimitedfield, row[1], month, year)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I honestly don't even know what I did to fix this. As I said in the comments "USER_Store_ID" and "USER_CenterID" contained the same data but one was text and one was numeric, so I added a field and copied the numeric field (CenterID) to the new field but converted it to text and name the new field "USER_StoreID". I thought this would fix the problem but it didn't. Then I just rearranged the order of DOSMonth and DOSYear in my expression and put the numeric field (CenterID) back where it was and it ran correctly. So once again not really sure what I did, but it works.

Here is my final code:

```
import arcpy
import datetime 
from datetime import timedelta
import time

#Document Start Time in-order to calculate Run Time
time1 = time.clock()

# Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\arcGIS_Shared\Python\CenterHeatMaps.gdb"

#Declare variables
fc = 'Open_Store_Centers'
fields = ['USER_market_id','USER_Store_ID','USER_Store_Center_Name', 'USER_Opening_Date']
fieldname = 'USER_market_id'

#Define WHERE clause statement
whereclause = """{} = 2000""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, fieldname))
sqlclause = (None, 'Order By USER_market_id, USER_Store_ID')

# loop through months
years = [2014, 2015, 2016, 2017]
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

for year in years:
    for month in months:
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_table = fc, field_names = fields, where_clause=whereclause, sql_clause=(None, 'ORDER BY USER_market_id, USER_Store_ID')) as cursor:
            #Loop through each row established in cursor
            for row in (cursor):
                # Set local variables for FeatureClasstoFeatureClass
                inFeatures = "PatientVisitsGeocoded"
                outLocation = r"C:\arcGIS_Shared\Python\CenterHeatMaps.gdb"
                outFeatureClass = "{2}{3}_NWPatientVisits{0}{1}".format(row[0], row[2], month, year)
                delimitedfield = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(arcpy.env.workspace,"USER_CenterID")

                expression = """{0} = {1} AND USER_DOSMonth = '{2}' AND USER_DOSYear = {3}""".format(delimitedfield, row[1], month, year)


#               Execute FeatureClassToFeatureClass
                arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(inFeatures, outLocation, outFeatureClass, expression)

                #Print Results
                print(row[2])
                count = arcpy.GetMessageCount()
                print (arcpy.GetMessage(count-1)) 

#Document End Time
time2 = time.clock()

#Run Time in seconds
runtime = (time2-time1)

print (str(timedelta(seconds=runtime)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it has something to do with your `expression`.  Try removing it from `arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(inFeatures, outLocation, outFeatureClass, expression)` to test if you get an output.  That will help narrow down the problem.  If you do get output then the problem is related to your expression.  If you don't then there's something else causing the lack of output.

Your `expression` line is a bit messy:

```
expression = delimitedfield + "= {0}".format(row[1]) + " AND USER_DOSYear = {0}".format(year) + " AND USER_DOSMonth = '{0}'".format(month)
```

Instead of concatenating a number of strings together, why not put them all into a single string using String formatting (as you've already partially done for each)?

```
expression = "{0} = {1} AND USER_DOSYear = {2} AND USER_DOSMonth = {3}".format(delimitedfield, row[1], year, month)
```

If removing/changing the expression doesn't make any difference I would look next at your `whereclause` in the Search Cursor.

---

On second look at your code, I noticed you've used the `AddFieldDelimiters()` twice.  Once refers to your `fc`, the other refers to your `arcpy.env.workspace`.  Try pointing both to the same to see if that changes anything.

---

Your comment that Year is `LONG` and Month is `TEXT` has hinted at a possible cause.  Try putting quote marks around the month value in your expression:

```
expression = """{0} = {1} AND USER_DOSYear = {2} AND USER_DOSMonth ='{3}' """.format(delimitedfield, row[1], year, month)
```

Comment: I removed the expression like you suggested and it produced an output with data. I then changed the expression as you suggested and it gave me the following error: `ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
An expected Field was not found or could not be retrieved properly.
An expected Field was not found or could not be retrieved properly. [PatientVisitsGeocoded]
Failed to execute (FeatureClassToFeatureClass)`

Comment: I also tried pointing the `AddFieldDelimiters()` to the same reference, but that didn't seem to change anything

Comment: @MattA. So there is an issue in your expression somehow.  Does the field `PatientVisitsGeocoded` exist?

Comment: That is the name of the feature class that all the other feature classes will be based off of. It is not a field within a table if that is what you mean

Comment: @MattA. OK Then there is another field the code is having issues with, either the wrong field type than expected, or a field not found.  See your error message - `An expected Field was not found`

Comment: `USER_DOSYear` is a "Long" Data Type, while `USER_DOSMonth` is "Text". What I don't understand is they will produce the right output if I run either of them by themselves, but when I try and string them together that is when the problems occur.

Comment: @MattA. I have updated my answer

Comment: It still gives me the same error

Comment: Any more suggestions? I still cant figure out the problem with my `expression`

Comment: There shoud be single quotes, not double quotes, around the 4th `string.format()` argument: `"""{0} = {1} AND USER_DOSYear = {2} AND USER_DOSMonth = '{3}'""".format(delimitedfield, row[1], year, month)`

Comment: @MattA. I have updated my answer to incorporate the correction suggested by @ GISGe

Comment: Midavalo and @GISGe Thanks for the input, unfortunately I already tried this and it didn't fix the problem. I have ESRI's help desk looking into it right now, they said it may be a bug. Either way I'll update this page with what I find out